# Why does continue in ForEach-Object operate like break?

Tags: powershell

```
$arr = @(1..10)
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -eq 5) { continue }
    "output $_"
}
```

Result:

```
output 1
output 2
output 3
output 4
```

---

```
$arr = @(1..10)
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -eq 5) { break }
    "output $_"
}
```

Result:

```
output 1
output 2
output 3
output 4
```

Why?

Answer (score 18):

Because `continue` and `break` are meant for loops and `foreach-object` is a cmdlet. The behaviour is not really what you expect, because it is just stopping the entire script ( add a statement after the original code and you will see that that statement doesn't run)

To get similar effect as continue used in a foreach loop, you may use `return`:

```
$arr = @(1..10)
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -eq 5){ return}
    "output $_"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

it is because the continue is applied to the  foreach loop (foreach $item in $collection) and not in the foreach-object cmdlet. try this:

```
$arr = @(1..10)
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -eq 5){ return}
    "output $_"
}
```

and this:

```
$arr = @(1..10)
 ForEach ($i in $arr) {
    if ($i -eq 5){ continue}
    "output $i"
}
```